# Reverse() is not working and so does unshift() in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

The issue is only there when I'm trying to reverse the user input, `reverse()` is returning the string as it is and so does the `unshift()`.

what I'm looking for is if the user enters `input - 1234` the `output should be 4,3,2,1`, but I'm getting is `output - 1,2,3,4`.

```js
const pahere = [];
const revephare = [];
let donereve = [];
let dff = document.getElementById("Udt1");

function tex(){
  if(dff. value == "") {
    console.log("enter text")
  }
  else {
    pahere.push(dff.value);
    console.log(dff.value);
    console.log(pahere);
    console.log(pahere.length);
    for(let i = 0; i < pahere.length; i++){
      revephare.push(pahere[i].split(""));
      pahere.pop();
    }
  }
  console.log("I should be splited",revephare);
  donereve = revephare.reverse();
  console.log("I should be reversed",donereve);
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background: #333;
    margin: 0;
}

h1{
    margin: 15px;
    color: white;
}
.holder{
    margin-left: 12px;
    width: 34em;
    height: 37em;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 51, 153,1);
    display: flex;
}

#Udt1 {
    width: 56%;
    height: 2em!important;
    text-align: center;
}

span {
    color: white;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.anshold {
    width: 154px;
    height: 34px;
    margin-left: 43em;
    position: relative;
    top: -592px !important;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 51, 153,1);
    text-align: center;
}

#udans{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
}

.btn {
    width: 16%;
    height: 2em!important;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 14px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Palidrom Checker</h1>
    <div class="holder">
        <span>Word goes here-</span>
        <input type="text" name="textin" label ="textin" id="Udt1" placeholder="Eg-Racecar">
        <button class="btn" onclick="tex()"> Check</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="anshold"><p id="udans">  </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `[ [ "a", "b", "c" ] ]` is an array with an array in it. When you reverse the array with one item, you get the same order back. Because there is only one item.

Comment: What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Don't put the array in another array. Or reverse the inner array. I'm not sure what is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to spliting Array `pahere[i].split("")`

```js
const pahere = [];
const revephare = [];
let donereve = [];
let dff = document.getElementById("Udt1");

function tex(){
  if(dff. value == "") {
    console.log("enter text")
  }
  else {
    pahere.push(dff.value);
    console.log(dff.value);
    console.log(pahere);
    console.log(pahere.length);
    for(let i = 0; i <dff.value.length; i++){
      revephare.push(dff.value[i]);
      pahere.pop();
    }
  }
  console.log("I should be splited",revephare);
  donereve = revephare.reverse();
  console.log("I should be reversed",donereve);
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    background: #333;
    margin: 0;
}

h1{
    margin: 15px;
    color: white;
}
.holder{
    margin-left: 12px;
    width: 34em;
    height: 37em;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 51, 153,1);
    display: flex;
}

#Udt1 {
    width: 56%;
    height: 2em!important;
    text-align: center;
}

span {
    color: white;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.anshold {
    width: 154px;
    height: 34px;
    margin-left: 43em;
    position: relative;
    top: -592px !important;
    border: 2px solid rgba(255, 51, 153,1);
    text-align: center;
}

#udans{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px;
}

.btn {
    width: 16%;
    height: 2em!important;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 14px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Palidrom Checker</h1>
    <div class="holder">
        <span>Word goes here-</span>
        <input type="text" name="textin" label ="textin" id="Udt1" placeholder="Eg-Racecar">
        <button class="btn" onclick="tex()"> Check</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="anshold"><p id="udans">  </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're using [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) incorrectly which gives you an array of arrays as a result

```js
revephare.push(pahere[i].split("")); // this line is incorrect
```

Replace it by the following to make it work

```js
// use spread operator to pass each element as a separate argument
revephare.push(...pahere[i].split(""));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i know you fixed the issue, you can achieve your output by this single line code, just try if you can

```
let reversed=(pahere.toString()).split("").map(Number).reverse();
```